# Beam theory: does finer meshing make any difference if the shape functions used are 3rd degree polynomials?

Tags: solid-mechanics

I'm studying the Finite element method for structural mechanics, and I'm reading [this source.](https://www.fe4d.com/fe/beam/1/)

3rd degree polynomials are used as shape functions for beam theory, since they are required to be continuously differentiable to the 4rd derivative.

It is said:

> If such a polynomial is used to derive the shape function, the solution will be exact.

I calculated the same example as in the article using RFEM. I used only two nodes for the side left to the load, and more nodes for the side on the right of the load.

[image]

The shape calculated by RFEM looks the same on both sides.

So my question is: **if 3rd level polynomials are used for interpolation, is there any advantage gained from using a finer mesh, if the result is exact even if we use only two nodes (one for each end of an element?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that a third-degree polynomial gives you the exact solution *always*. For example, for a cantilever beam with a uniform load, you get a fourth-order solution in the displacement.